# ProductFlavor in Module Library only

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-productflavors

I have a Library Module that has 2 flavors. What I want is that the flavors are only containing the module and not in the app itself but i get dependency issues.
This is the gradle file of my module "testlib":

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    flavorDimensions "exampleflav"
    publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        flav1 {}
        flav2 {}
    }
```

the app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prose.flavortest"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(path:':testlib', configuration: 'flav1Release')
}
```

When i try to sync i get the following error:
...

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :testlib.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :testlib.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

...

Iam aware that it will work when i add

```
flavorDimensions "exampleflav"
publishNonDefault true
productFlavors {
    flav1 {}
    flav2 {}
}
```

to my app gradle file but that is exactly what I Dont want. Is there any chance to have the flavors in the lib only without adding them to the app itself?